# Multiplying constant to an expression

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am multiplying constant to an expression which can be seen from below. But the final expression is getting reduced. I just want it to be multiplied.

```
(x^2 (-((1. (2 - 1/x)^3 x^5)/(
Sqrt[1 - x^2] (0. + 1. x^2)^1.5)) + ((2 - 1/x)^3 x^5)/((1 - x^2)^(
3/2) (0. + 1. x^2)^0.5) + (3 (2 - 1/x)^2 x^2)/(
Sqrt[1 - x^2] (0. + 1. x^2)^0.5) + (4 (2 - 1/x)^3 x^3)/(
Sqrt[1 - x^2] (0. + 1. x^2)^0.5)))/(3 (2 - 1/x)^2)   *  (4)
```

Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `x` have a value? Try `Clear[x]`

Comment: There is no value of x.

Comment: Can you describe more clearly how the result is "getting reduced" and what you want instead?

Comment: Maybe `HoldForm[...]` - but it's not much different from the input.

Comment: When I am trying to simplify the above expression, it says no interpretation available.

Answer (score 0):

It simplifies ok.

```
expr = (x^2 (-((1. (2 - 1/x)^3 x^5)/
           (Sqrt[1 - x^2] (0. + 1. x^2)^1.5)) +
        ((2 - 1/x)^3 x^5)/
         ((1 - x^2)^(3/2) (0. + 1. x^2)^0.5) +
        (3 (2 - 1/x)^2 x^2)/
         (Sqrt[1 - x^2] (0. + 1. x^2)^0.5) +
        (4 (2 - 1/x)^3 x^3)/
         (Sqrt[1 - x^2] (0. + 1. x^2)^0.5)))/
    (3 (2 - 1/x)^2)*(4);

Simplify[expr] // InputForm
```

> (-2.6666666666666665*x^4*(-1.5*x^6*(x^2)^0.5 + 1.*x^7*(x^2)^0.5 + 1.5*x*(x^2)^1.5 - 
>      4.5*(x^2)^2.5 + x^5*(-0.25*(x^2)^0.5 - 3.*(x^2)^1.5) + 
>      x^4*(1.375*(x^2)^0.5 + 3.*(x^2)^1.5) + x^3*(-0.75*(x^2)^0.5 + 3.25*(x^2)^1.5)))/
>    ((0.5 - 1.*x)^2*(x^2)^2.*Sqrt[1 - x^2]*(-1. + x^2))